# The refcursor return type is not returning result

Tags: postgresql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION multi_product(p_pid in varchar) 
    RETURNS  refcursor AS $$
    DECLARE
    ref_cursor REFCURSOR;
     BEGIN
    OPEN ref_cursor FOR SELECT * FROM product_mst where pid=p_pid; -- Open the first cursor
     RETURN (ref_cursor);
     END;
     $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The `refcursor` is not returning any rows. It is behaving as below.

Execution1:

```
BEGIN;
SELECT multi_product('1122');  --O/P -- refcursor
COMMIT;
```

Execution2:

```
BEGIN;
SELECT multi_product('1122');
FETCH 4   from  "<unnamed portal 11>";  -- SQL Error [34000]: ERROR: cursor "<unnamed portal 11>" does not exist
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Why don't you use `returns table`? Much easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

You should assign a name to the cursor in the defining function, for example:

```
ref_cursor REFCURSOR := 'curs';
```

Then you use

```
FETCH ALL FROM curs;
```

to get all results.

Here is a complete example:

````
CREATE FUNCTION multi_product() RETURNS refcursor
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$DECLARE
   ref_cursor refcursor := 'curs';
BEGIN
   OPEN ref_cursor FOR SELECT 42 AS col;
   RETURN ref_cursor;
END;$$;

BEGIN;

SELECT multi_product();

 multi_product 
---------------
 curs
(1 row)

FETCH ALL FROM curs;

 col 
-----
  42
(1 row)

COMMIT;```
````

Comment: Hi Albe,                                                                                                                               I have tried it .Throwing the error.      FETCH ALL FROM curs; SQL Error [34000]: ERROR: cursor "curs" does not exist

Comment: Well, it works with PostgreSQL. Perhaps you are closing the transaction before the `FETCH`.